# Javascript closure not loading?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am starting a simple website and attempting to code my Javascript using closures.  My first goal is to show an alert box when the page loads.  But this is failing.  The head section of my page contains:

```
<script src="js/dukegen.shell.js"></script>
<script src="js/dukegen.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = dukegen.init();
</script>
```

This is dukegen.shell.js:

```
dukegen.shell = (function() {
    vat initModule = function () {
        alert("STATRTED");
    };

    return {initModule: initModule};
}());
```

This is dukegen.js:

```
var dukegen = (function () {
    var init = function () {
        dukegen.shell.initModule();

    };
    return {init: init};
}());
```

When I load the page, the execution errors ("Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'initModule' of undefined") at dukegen.shell.initModule(); .  My untrained eye cannot spot the problem.  Both my javascript files are in the same folder.

Comment: Try `window.onload = dukegen.init`, no parens.

Comment: No dice. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order in which you include the scripts:

```
<script src="js/dukegen.js"></script>
<script src="js/dukegen.shell.js"></script>
```

At the moment `js/dukegen.shell.js` is executed, the `dukegen` object does not exist yet, hence the assignment of `dukegen.shell = ...` will throw an error. Or if for some reason the object exists, you would overwrite with the second script.

Also make sure you fix all syntax errors (`vat initModule = function () {`) and use `window.onload = dukegen.init`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var initModule = function () {
        alert("STATRTED");
    };
```

not vat.

Comment: I apologize, what is vat?

Comment: @badgerduke: `vat initModule = function () {` (look at your code)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dukegen = (function (shell) {
    var init = function () {
        shell.initModule();

    };
    return {init: init};
}(dukegen.shell));
```

Comment: Still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Is the snippet from the head section correct?  You're including `dukegen.shell.js`, defining dukegen.shell, then overwriting dukegen in dukegen.js

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a namespace, ok? But you're overwriting it... I think the best way is:

```
var dukegen = {}; //your namespace, ok?

//here we are adding an atribute to your namespace, not overwriting it like you did before
dukegen.main = (function () { 
        var init = function () {
            dukegen.shell.initModule();

        };
        return {init: init};
    }());

//and creating another module
dukegen.shell = (function() {
        var initModule = function () {
            alert("STATRTED");
        };

        return {initModule: initModule};
    }());
//bootstrapping your app
dukegen.main.init();

// and a tip, always use dependency inject to call another module, like this:
 dukegen.main = (function (myShellModuleOrAnyOtherModule) { 
            var init = function () {
                myShellModuleOrAnyOtherModule.initModule();

            };
            return {init: init};
        }(dukegen.shell));
```

Comment: Did you try to run the code? You will get an error because `dukegen` is `undefined`.